# Morgan and a String - What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve Morgan and a String problem from Hackerrank. I am not understanding why below code runs infinitely.

Solution approach : Finding the characters pointed by `indexa` and `indexb` to check and append to string `fin` till `indexa` or `indexb` are less than size of the strings. Doing it recursively.

Once `indexa` or `indexb` are greater than size of the string, I am appending the remaining string to `fin`.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
      std::string fin = "";
      int indexa = 0;
      int indexb = 0;
    
    
    // Complete the morganAndString function below.
    string morganAndString(string a, string b) {
    std::string ret = "";
    
     int sizea = a.size();
     int sizeb = b.size();
    
     int curra;
     int currb;
     while((indexa < sizea) && (indexb < sizeb) )
     { 
    
        curra = a[indexa];
        currb = b[indexb];
        if(curra <= currb)
        {
            fin += a[indexa];
            indexa++;
        }
        else if(currb < curra)
        {
            fin +=  b[indexb];
            indexb++;
        }
        
        morganAndString(a, b); // resursively calling till indexa or indexb are less than size of string a and b respectively. 
     }
     
//append fin with the remaining string for which i have not reached till end. 
     if(indexa == sizea && indexb < sizeb  )
     {   
         for(;indexb < sizeb; indexb++ )
         {
         fin += b[indexb];
         }
     }
     
     else if(indexb == sizeb && indexa < sizea  )
     {   
         for(;indexa < sizea; indexa++ )
         {
         fin += a[indexa];
         }
     }
     
     indexa = 0;
     indexb = 0;
     
     ret = fin;
    
     fin = "";
    
     std::cout<<ret<<std::endl;
     return ret;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));
    
        int t;
        cin >> t;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    
        for (int t_itr = 0; t_itr < t; t_itr++) {
            string a;
            getline(cin, a);
    
            string b;
            getline(cin, b);
    
            string result = morganAndString(a, b);
    
            fout << result << "\n";
        }
    
        fout.close();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

The code goes to infinite loop. Could you please help me to understand what is wrong here ?

Comment: Inside the while loop, you call `morganAndString` with the exact same arguments you started with, so it's going to do exactly the same thing. The variables in a function aren't just local to the function; they're local to that particular *call* of the function, so when you call the function again you get a new set of variables.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I am incrementing indexa and indexb which are global, so when i call morganAndString resucrively I am comparing character from the updated indexa and indexb. Other local variables inside the functions are updated on every call.

I am reaching end if the function with right string, but something goes wrong and whole of the function gets called again.

Comment: You present a solution, but not the problem.  What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @damien it is "Morgan and string" problem from hackerrank. My code is going to infinite loop even after control reaching end of the function

Comment: Yes, but what is the  *Morgan and string* problem? How coud we guess? All important information must be copied in the post as text.